# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError on object initialization

Tags: java

I have an instance variable, like so:

```
PathFinder finder;
```

(this is using Kevin Glass' A* tutorial, so the PathFinder class is in the same file, link here: http://cokeandcode.com/index.html?page=tutorials/tilemap2)

Anyways, when I do

```
finder = new AStarPathFinder(currentMap, 1000, true);
```

I get a Exception in thread ""AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError".

currentMap is an instance of my Map class, and yes it is initialized. 1000 represents the maximum tile distance that will be searched, and the boolean represents diagonal movement true/false. Oh well I'll just throw the constructor at you:

```
public AStarPathFinder(TileBasedMap map, int maxSearchDistance, boolean allowDiagMovement) {
    this(map, maxSearchDistance, allowDiagMovement, new ClosestHeuristic());
}
```

I know it has something to do with static initializers, but I'm not too sure what else. Oh, and I tried to initialize an instance of the same AStarPathFinder class in another class, and I got the same result.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Never mind, stupid me. I didn't read the full stack trace, I only read the top(usually), there was just a disagreement between AStarPathFinder and its parent class on one of the methods(somehow the IDE didn't highlight it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the full stack trace, and the error was that the parameters for a method in the parent class and in the child class wasn't the same, somehow the IDE just didn't make any notification.

Comment: This was my hunch, or at least something like it - in most cases `ExceptionInInitializerError` is actually caused by another exception further down the trace.